# Cant call layout from scrollView

Tags: android

I want to zeptat.Vytvořil I have in my application scrollView where I have about 20 buttons

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="423dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollLinear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2222dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAlkohol"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/carka"
                android:onClick="OnButtonAlkohol"
                android:text="@string/alkohol"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
  </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is just an excerpt, and there is only one .To do when I click on it so I opened a new Layout.Udělal I therefore new class where I want to control every one button. (Again, there is only one)

**Ok here is Update it is my class hou you say i must change**

```
public class VyberTemata extends Activity   {
    Button btnAlkohol;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
           setContentView(R.layout.aplikace_slova);
           btnAlkohol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAlkohol);    
        }


public void OnButtonAlkohol (View v)
{

    btnAlkohol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAlkohol);
    setContentView(R.layout.aplikace_slova);
}
```

**Here is this error**

```
09-22 17:19:46.079: I/Choreographer(1623): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-22 17:19:46.869: D/AndroidRuntime(1623): Shutting down VM
09-22 17:19:46.869: W/dalvikvm(1623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3fa8288)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method OnButtonAlkohol(View) in the activity class cz.betaverze.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnAlkohol'
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3578)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: OnButtonAlkohol [class android.view.View]
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3571)
09-22 17:19:46.920: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does you app crash? What is the error message?

Comment: if i start App so i have there splash screen.Then he go out and i see viewFlipper there i choose category and i go to scrollView and there is 20 buttons if i click on Button (for example Alkohol) i want go next,there is finish .But whole way is everythink ok but if im in scroll View and click on button my application hangs.and show window Application doesn't work.And now i go chack it in android emulator and write ou where is bugs

Comment: @touby What you want to do on button click?

Comment: i need open layout aplikace_slova

Comment: @touby I edited my answer, if you want more help you should post the code of your MainActivity class where you are starting the new Activity

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setContentView()` before initializing the button.

Also, you should place your code into the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
   setContentView(R.layout.aplikace_slova);
   btnAlkohol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAlkohol);    
}
```

--EDIT--

Furthermore, I see in your logcat you are trying to call the function `OnButtonAlkohol()` from your `MainActivity` class. You probably want to get rid of that function altogether since the logic is now placed in `onCreate()`(as it should be).

Comment: it doesn't work:/and now if i click on Alkohol in scrollView thus the application hangs and shuts down :/ Do you think could you give me some contact on you ? Facebook,Skype or somethink _ ? i'm going to write you and send you my project and you can check it and help me ?

Comment: @touby That is not how StackOverFlow works, you can post relevant code here and I will then help you with finding the error. Could you post your updated Activity class?

Comment: Ok i will change my question